# how to split columns in two parts after first

Tags: sql, postgresql, split

there is a column of type **text** in postgresql
and have data in form

```
aa.bbb.cc.dddd
ee.fff.gg.hh.iiii
kk.ffg.hjf
```

I want to split it into two parts after first `.` as follows:

```
aa   bbb.cc.dddd
ee   fff.gg.hh.iiii
kk   ffg.hjf
```

What query can I use to do so?

I have tried

```
SELECT split_part(col_name, '.', 1) AS part1,
       split_part(col_name,'.',2) AS part2 
from table_name;
```

But this is splitting it into aa and bbb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `strpos` to find the first `.`, then use `substr()`

```
select left(col_name, strpos(col_name, '.') - 1) as part1, 
       substr(col_name, strpos(col_name, '.') + 1) as part2
from table_name
```